# Java EE: variable number of input text

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, xhtml

I have an xhtml page in which there is a form to create an Event for an online Calendar and at the end of the form there is the possibilities to invite some users registered to the site.

At the moment there are three fields in which is possible to insert an email (Invite User 1, Invite User 2, Invite User 3 at the bottom of the code), but i want that at the beginning there are zero fields but simply a button called ***"Add user"*** that when clicked adds a new field. Then it's possible to click this button a various number of time and so there is no limit to the generated fields.

Here is the code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Create Event</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <p:panel header="Create Event Form">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="regGrid">

                <h:outputLabel for="name">Name:</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{createBean.event.eventname}"/><br/>

                <h:outputLabel for="city">City</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="city" value="#{createBean.event.city}"/><br/>

                <h:outputLabel for="inviteone">Invite User 1:</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="inviteone" value="#{createBean.invited1}"/><br/>

                <h:outputLabel for="inviteone">Invite User 2:</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="invitetwo" value="#{createBean.invited2}"/><br/>

                <h:outputLabel for="inviteone">Invite User 3:</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="invitethree" value="#{createBean.invited3}"/><br/>



            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton value="Create Event" update="regGrid"
                                 action="#{createBean.saveEvent()}" />



        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

In conclusion I want to remove the last 3 couples of h:outputLabel - p:inputText and ***simply add a Button that when clicked generate a couple*** of h:outputLabel - p:inputText, clicked again and another couple h:outputLabel - p:inputText.   (Then I am already able to pass the values to the Bean in a proper way ;)  )

Answer (score 1):

Try with **ui:repeat** tag and let jsf re-render the container:

```
<p:commandButton value="Add friend"
                 action="#{createBean.addInvited}" 
                 update="container" />

<p:outputPanel id="container">
    <ui:repeat value="#{createBean.invitedList}" var="invited" varStatus="myVarStatus">
        <h:outputLabel>Invite User #{myVarStatus.index}:</h:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText value="#{invited}"/>
        <br/>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Later today I'll try it and I'll let you know! Thanks :)